Assign Default Taxonomy to Post When Created
I'd like to associate new posts created under a custom post type to automatically be given a custom taxonomy term. As a heads up here are the parameters
Custom Post Type Name: business_ser_dir_ltg
Custom Taxonomy Name: secondary-listing-category
Term Name: Business Services
Term Slug: business-services
function bus_default_terms( $post_id, $post, $update ){
if ( 'business_ser_dir_ltg' == $post->post_type) {

$default_term = '5480'; // ID of the required term
$taxonomy = "business-services"; // slug of the taxonomy

wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $default_term, $taxonomy );

}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'bus_default_terms', 30, 3 );

This is the code I created, but when I create a new post it does not automatically assign the term Business Services to the newly created post.

for $taxonomy, it's the slug of the taxonomy (secondary-listing-category) and not the slug of the term. look the documentation here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/

Thank you @Dao for your answer. I was able to figure out the solution. The answer is below:
/*Set Default Taxonomy to Business Services*/
function bus_default_terms($post_id, $post, $update){
    if('business_ser_dir_ltg' == $post->post_type){
        
        $default_term = 'Business Services'; // Name of the required term
        $taxonomy     = "secondary-listing-category"; // slug of the taxonomy
        
        wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $default_term, $taxonomy);
        
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'bus_default_terms', 30, 3);


First of all, the third param of wp_set_post_terms must be a taxonomy slug, in this case, it's secondary-listing-category.
Second, the term ID should be in numeric type instead of string. Read the explanation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/#user-contributed-notes
Therefore, the correct code should be
function bus_default_terms($post_id, $post, $update){
    if('business_ser_dir_ltg' == $post->post_type){
        
        $default_term = 5480; // ID of the required term
        $taxonomy     = "secondary-listing-category"; // slug of the taxonomy
        
        wp_set_post_terms($post_id, intval($default_term), $taxonomy);
        
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'bus_default_terms', 30, 3);


This is getting closer. The problem with this it adds the term 5480 automatically to the post instead of Business Services. I've changed the 5480 to Business Services and now it is working.
